Remove duplicate lines in Azure Data Factory
I have a datastream with ~ 15 columns. I want to delete every row in my dataset that is already identical and keep unique ones. If there is one value differently in a row, I want to keep it.
Unfortunately the columns are dynamic, so I don't know in advance all names of columns.
Example data:
matnr,vendor,sparepart,text,value,warehouse
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valve, 2, spain
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valve, 2, spain
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valve, 2, spain
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valveXX, 2, spain

After transformation:
matnr,vendor,sparepart,text,value,warehouse
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valve, 2, spain
12345, mercedes, xlm12, valveXX, 2, spain

What would be the fastest way? Found plenty solutions but they solve the problem that duplicates are only checked by one column specific (e.g. matnr).

Did you try any approach? are you getting any error?

I used the aggregate function and it works, but the problem is that I have to name the columns in advanced on which I want to group. And I dont know them :(

Have you considered using sha2(256, columns()) to compute a hash value/fingerprint for each row and dedupe based on that?

I know with a derived column I can use sha2(256, concat(columns())) to make a hash per column. Again I need to name all columns in advance which is difficult :/

You can use sha2(256,columns()) expression in the aggregate transformation as suggested by @ray to achieve your requirement.
Take Aggregate transformation after your source and use the sha2(256,columns()) expression and give any column name to it in the Group by section as shown below. Here, columns() will give all the columns names as an array.

In the aggregate section, use a column pattern and take only the first row (first($$)) of every group by giving the condition of true().

This will give the distinct rows irrespective of the structure of the source data. But it will add the extra column that was used for grouping.

To remove, use Rule-based mapping in the select transformation and give the condition as name!='new_column'.

Now, it will give the expected results.

Whatever the source columns, it will give the desired result upon running the dataflow from pipeline.

When I create a aggreate flow and click on "group by" I want to add "sha2(256,columns())" exactly as lined out by you, but I cannot paste something in. I only can select exisitng columns ?

Click on open expression https://i.imgur.com/RPsSiWg.png and here, specify the column name and expression https://i.imgur.com/KwgjEo0.png and click on save and finish.

Perfect! Thank you!
